# viewpager2 makes espresso tests not running OK

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-viewpager2

I have an Android app composed of 2 activities. In the second activity, I have a viewpager with 3 tabs. In one of this tabs, when I click a button, a dialog box is open and I can click on some elements of this dialog.
This piece of code is runing fine
I also have Espresso tests in a test class.
If I run the tests at the test class level, all tests pass OK.

I have now migrated the viewpager to viewpager2.

The app runs fine

If I play each test separately, the test passes OK

If I run the tests at the test class level, the first test passes OK, but all the next ones fail.

Any idea of what is happening and how to fix it?